# How to change tint color of a rightCalloutAccessory on Mapbox?

Tags: ios, mapbox

Is there a way to change the tint color of an annotations `rightCalloutAccessory`, without changing the tint color of the `mapView`?

For example, I'd like to set the maps tint color to white so that the users current location and info icon in the bottom right are white, but I'd like for the annotations `calloutAccessory` to be blue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want [`mapView:rightCalloutAccessoryViewForAnnotation:`](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/api/Protocols/MGLMapViewDelegate.html#//api/name/mapView:rightCalloutAccessoryViewForAnnotation:), which can be used like so:

```
- (UIView *)mapView:(__unused MGLMapView *)mapView rightCalloutAccessoryViewForAnnotation:(__unused id<MGLAnnotation>)annotation
{
    UIButton *rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoLight];
    rightCalloutAccessoryView.tintColor = [UIColor blueColor];

    return rightCalloutAccessoryView;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you want to change the tint color of the annotation view. You can do this by calling the `MKMapViewDelegate` protocol's function :

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier("annotationView") as? MKPinAnnotationView

    if annotationView == nil {
        annotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "annotationView")
    }

    annotationView?.canShowCallout = true
    annotationView?.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.DetailDisclosure)
    annotationView?.rightCalloutAccessoryView?.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    return annotationView
}
```

Comment: Your answer is for MapKit, while the question asks for Mapbox. Definitely the right track, though.